# packer: Unknown builder hcloud

Tags: packer, packer-builder

I am running a Hashicorp builder script, which works fine on the machines of colleges, but it fails on  my machine.

What could be the reason?

```
packer build foo/bar/controlPlane-hcloud-amd64.json

Error: Failed to initialize build "hcloud"

error initializing builder 'hcloud': Unknown builder hcloud
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using the new version (1.9.x) while your colleges use the old version.

You need to install the builder first. In your case:

```
packer plugins install github.com/hashicorp/hcloud
```